# bouce effect not working on mozilla firefox

Tags: firefox, jsfiddle, effect, bounce

I work on bouce effect and i would like to know why this example doesn't work on firefox ???

`http://jsfiddle.net/Nath/34eMN/`

css part:

```
div { -webkit-animation: bounce 1.5s infinite ease-in-out; }
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
0%, 20%, 60%, 100%  { -webkit-transform: translateY(0); }
40%                 { -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px); }
80%                 { -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px); }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because all your transforms are specified to webkit which is not Firefox. Remove the `-webkit-` part and see what happens. Firefox does not need prefixes and only webkit browsers do.

Comment: @furomlavi Remove the -webkit- part. I don't recall whether Firefox needs -moz- or not but I don't think so.

Comment: @furomlavi Firefox does not need the prefixes.

Comment: If we delete all -webkit- 

it works fine, thanks @Rob, hope it'll not create another problem ;D

Comment: Google for "css prefixer" - there are numerous tools that will convert your unprefixed code to code that has all the required prefixes for all the major browsers.

Comment: The problem isn't resolved, because when we delete -webkit- it's on chrome that it doesn't work now lol

Comment: @furomlavi Which version of Chrome? Chrome no longer uses prefixes and doesn't use webkit. For older versions, you need -webkit.